# Differential equations - using a separation of variables ansatz

Tags: calculus

Say we have a differential equation and we ansatz the solution is of the form $X(x)T(t)$ and we end up with, $$\frac{T''}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}-m^{2}$$

We get that $T''=-k^{2}T$ where $k^{2} = e^{2}+m^{2}$ and $-e^{2}$ is the constant that we have set the other side to. but how do we then get that $X''=-e^{2}X$ do we not get and extra $+m^{2}X$ on the end?

Comment: $\frac{T''}{T}=-k^2=\frac{X''}{X}-m^2, X''=(-k^2+m^2)X$  You can just solve it without defining $k$ in the beginning

Comment: But if I wanted to get them into the for $Z''=-v^{2}Z$ how does the above work?

Comment: @Jlatmer . What is the original differential equation that you have to solve? I suspect a muddle in your $\frac{T''}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}-m^{2}$ .